# How to calculate the Cosine similarity between two tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have two normalized tensors and I need to calculate the cosine similarity between these tensors. How do I do it with TensorFlow?

```
cosine(normalize_a,normalize_b)

    a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name="input_placeholder_a")
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name="input_placeholder_b")
    normalize_a = tf.nn.l2_normalize(a,0)        
    normalize_b = tf.nn.l2_normalize(b,0)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name="input_placeholder_a")
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name="input_placeholder_b")
normalize_a = tf.nn.l2_normalize(a,0)        
normalize_b = tf.nn.l2_normalize(b,0)
cos_similarity=tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(normalize_a,normalize_b))
sess=tf.Session()
cos_sim=sess.run(cos_similarity,feed_dict={a:[1,2,3],b:[2,4,6]})
```

This prints `0.99999988`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Is the cosine similarity formula getting simplified by normalizing the inputs first? your formula seems to have less things than the one from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity

Comment: If you will not normalize first, then after you calculate the inner product a*b you have to divide by the product of the norms of a and b. However, if you normalize in advance, you don't need to do that. This is because normalize_a=a/||a|| (and similarly for b).

Comment: why not matmul?

Comment: tf.matmul() is matrix multiplication, tf.multiply() is element-wise multiplication

Answer (score 25):

Times change. With the latest TF API, this can be computed by calling `tf.losses.cosine_distance`.

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


x = tf.constant(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 10)) 
y = tf.constant(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 10))
s = tf.losses.cosine_distance(tf.nn.l2_normalize(x, 0), tf.nn.l2_normalize(y, 0), dim=0)
print(tf.Session().run(s))
```

Of course, `1 - s` is the cosine similarity!

Comment: why is 1-s the cosine similarity?

Comment: because ```s``` is the cosine distance, not the similarity.

Comment: The ```1-s``` isn't needed. The function is called distance, but returns similarity. I think because it's in tf.losses. Have a look at the code, i might be wrong. Line 274.  losses = 1 - math_ops.reduce_sum(radial_diffs, axis=(dim,), keep_dims=True) https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py

Comment: @RajarsheeMitra can this be done for an entire matrix? meaning cosine distance between a vector `v` and all the rows in a matrix assuming each row is a vector of same dimension as `v` ?

Comment: @ajaanbaahu Yes.

Comment: @patrick.ryan93 1-s is needed. math_ops.reduce_sum(radial_diffs, axis=(dim,), keep_dims=True) is cosine similarity.

Answer (score 2):

Cosine similarity between `a` and `b`  :

```
tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity()(a, b)
```

Comment: Tip: This converges to `-1.0` since it's meant to be used a as loss function. If you want something that converges to `1.0` use `tf.keras.metrics.CosineSimilarity` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize you vector or matrix like this:

```
[batch_size*hidden_num]
states_norm=tf.nn.l2_normalize(states,dim=1)
[batch_size * embedding_dims]
embedding_norm=tf.nn.l2_normalize(embedding,dim=1)
#assert hidden_num == embbeding_dims
after mat [batch_size*embedding]
user_app_scores = tf.matmul(states_norm,embedding_norm,transpose_b=True)
```