# Is there a way of using cosine similarity instead of dot product in python (sklearn/keras)

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning

I just started using Sklearn (MLPRegressor) and Keras (Sequential, with Dense layers).

Today I read [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.05870.pdf) paper describing how using cosine similarity instead of the dot product improves the performance. This basically says that if we replace `f(w^Tx)` with `f((w^Tx)/(|x||w|))`, i.e. we don't just feed the dot product to the activation function but we normalize it, we get a better and quicker performance.

Is there a way of doing this in Python, specifically in MLPRegressor in SKlearn (or another), or in Keras? (maybe TensorFlow?)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357732/how-to-calculate-the-cosine-similarity-between-two-tensors/43358711#43358711

Answer (score 1):

Sklearn uses prebuilt networks, so no. I also don't think it's possible in Keras, as it has prebuilt layers.

It sure can be implemented in Tensorflow though. Note that in TF you can explicitly define layers.

For example in [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/vinhkhuc/e53a70f9e5c3f55852b0) you'd need to add normalization in line 25, namely you can divide output rows `tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_1))` by appropriate norms of input rows (you can get them using `tf.nn.l2_normalize` with `dim=1`)

Comment: Thank you! So basically I would have: `h    = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_1) \ tf.matmul(tf.nn.l2_normalize(X, dim=1), tf.nn.l2_normalize(w_1))` ?

Comment: or maybe 


`h = tf.nnsigmoid(tf.divide(tf.matmul(X, w_1), tf.matmul(tf.nn.l2_normalize(X, dim=1), tf.nn.l2_normalize(w_1))))`

Comment: also, running the example we see that the test accuracy is 100% vs 96% of training??? How is that possible?