# Parallel Cosine similarity of two large files with each other

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, sparse-matrix, cosine-similarity, gnu-parallel

I have two files: A and B

```
A has 400,000 lines each having 50 float values
B has 40,000 lines having 50 float values.
```

For every line in B, I need to find corresponding lines in A which have >90% similarity (cosine).

For linear search and computation, the code takes ginormous computing time. (40-50 hours)

Reaching out to the community for suggestions on how to fasten the process (link of blogs/resources such as AWS/Cloud to be used to achieve it). Have been stuck with this for quite a while!

[There were mentions of rpud/rpudplus to do it, but can't seem to perform them on cloud resources]

N.B. as requested, the code for cosine similarity is:

```
for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
    line1 = line1[:-1]
    cnt = cnt + 1
    l2X = [float(i) for i in line2.split()]
    f3 = open(enLabelValues, 'r')
    f4 = open(enVectorValues, 'r')
    print cnt
    cnt_j = 0
    for line3, line4 in zip(f3, f4):
        line3 = line3[:-1]
        l4X = [float(i) for i in line4.split()]
        ########This is the line for spatial cosine similarity
        result = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(l2X, l4X)
        cnt_j = cnt_j + 1
        if(result > float(0.95)):
            if line3 not in a.keys():
                a[line3] = True
                fLabel_2.write(line3+"\n")
                fX_2.write(line4)
        fLabel_2.flush()
        fX_2.flush()
        os.fsync(fLabel_2.fileno())
        os.fsync(fX_2.fileno())
```

Comment: If downvoting, please share why it is being downvoted. It is a genuine question I have been working on. Let's not be bitter and be constructive

Comment: Where is the code to measure the similarity for 1 line please?

Comment: What sort of a machine do you have available for this?

Comment: @MarkSetchell added the code. I was using CPU 8GB, but have GPU accesses as well. Not sure how to go about parallelizing them. (Since every line in A is to be compared with B, we could in theory parallelize by duplicating B and having parts of A compared with the replicated files for B)

Comment: Yikes! I'm not a bit surprised it's taking 40+ hours. Your code isn't at all parallelised, you are using Python and you aren't using SIMD. Also, although this would be more relevant for a parallelised version, you don't pre-compute the magnitudes just once nor do you write the files as binary. And yes, do run multiple threads/processes where each one loads the smaller (B) of the datasets into memory and checks a subset of A against it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, I figured I should go for GPU codes. So, reached out to the community before re-inventing the wheel for established solutions. Was trying out rpud/rpudplus codes, but they are apparently not readily available in the cloud solutions! Will add details when I figure out the slicker approach!

Comment: Python is horrible for doing mass computations. What it _is_ good at is controlling libraries that do mass computations. So see if you can express your problem using matrices and then use TensorFlow, NumPy, or similar tools. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357732/how-to-calculate-the-cosine-similarity-between-two-tensors looks relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can generate synthetic files of 40,000 and 400,000 lines with 50 samples per line and process them in around 2 minutes 18 seconds on a reasonable 4 core (+hyperthreading) desktop iMac in my clumsy style of C++ without any SIMD optimisation (by me) using **GNU Parallel**.

Here is the top-level script. You can see it generates the test data in `"a.txt"` and `"b.txt"`. Then it *"compresses"* `"b.txt"` to an identical binary representation, with the pre-computed magnitude appended to each line. Finally, it numbers the lines in `"a.txt"` and passes them into **GNU Parallel** which splits the lines into groups of around 5,200 lines and starts a group of 8 parallel processes to compare each of those lines with the 40,000 lines in B.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate test data - a.txt b.txt
./generate

# Preprocess b.txt into binary with precomputed magitudes save as B
./preprocess

# Process file A in batches
cat -n a.txt | parallel --block-size 2M --line-buffer --pipe ./process {#}
```

Here is the generate.cpp program to synthesise data:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include "common.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int line,sample;
   ofstream a("a.txt");
   if (!a.is_open()){
      cerr << "ERROR: Unable to open output file";
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   for(line=0;line<ALINES;line++){
      for(sample=0;sample<SAMPLESPERLINE;sample++){
         a << (float)rand()*100/RAND_MAX << " ";
      }
      a << endl;
   }
   a.close();
   ofstream b("b.txt");
   if (!b.is_open()){
      cerr << "ERROR: Unable to open output file";
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   for(line=0;line<BLINES;line++){
      for(sample=0;sample<SAMPLESPERLINE;sample++){
         b << (float)rand()*100/RAND_MAX << " ";
      }
      b << endl;
   }
   b.close();
}
```

Here is the preprocess.cpp code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include "common.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

   std::ifstream btxt("b.txt");
   std::ofstream bbin("B",std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
   if (!btxt.is_open()){
      std::cerr << "ERROR: Unable to open input file";
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   if (!bbin.is_open()){
      std::cerr << "ERROR: Unable to open output file";
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   int l=0;
   std::string line;
   std::vector<float> v;
   v.resize(SAMPLESPERLINE+1);
   while (std::getline(btxt,line)){
      std::istringstream iss(line);
      v.clear();
      float f;
      double magnitude;
      magnitude=0.0;
      int s=0;
      while (iss >> f){
         v[s]=(f);
         magnitude+=(double)f*f;
         s++;
      }
      // Append the magnitude to the end of the "line"
      v[s]=(float)sqrt(magnitude);
      // Write the samples and magnitide in binary to the output file
      bbin.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&v[0]),(SAMPLESPERLINE+1)*sizeof(float));
      l++;
   }
   btxt.close();
   bbin.close();

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the `common.h` file:

```
const int ALINES=400000;
const int BLINES=40000;
const int SAMPLESPERLINE=50;
```

And here is the `process.cpp` code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include "common.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

   if(argc!=2){
      std::cerr << "Usage: process JOBNUM" << std::endl;
      exit(1);
   }
   int JobNum=std::atoi(argv[1]);
   std::cerr << "Starting job: " << JobNum << std::endl;

   // Load B
   std::ifstream bbin("B",std::ios::binary);
   if (!bbin.is_open()){
      std::cerr << "ERROR: Unable to open B";
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   int l=0;
   std::array<float,SAMPLESPERLINE+1> record;
   std::vector<std::array<float,SAMPLESPERLINE+1>> B;
   B.resize(BLINES);
   for(l=0;l<BLINES;l++){
      // Read one record of 50 floats and their magnitude
      bbin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&B[l][0]),sizeof(float)*(SAMPLESPERLINE+1));
   }
   bbin.close();

   // Process all lines read from stdin, each line prepended by its line number
   // Format is:
   // <line number in file "a.txt"> <SAMPLE0> <SAMPLE1> ... <SAMPLE49>
   int nLines=0;
   std::string line;
   while (std::getline(std::cin,line)){
      nLines++;
      std::istringstream iss(line);
      std::vector<float> A;
      A.resize(SAMPLESPERLINE);
      float f;
      int Alineno;
      int s=0;
      iss >> Alineno;
      double dMag=0.0;
      while (iss >> f){
         A[s++]=f;
         dMag+=(double)f*f;
      }
      // Root magnitude
      float AMagnitude=(float)sqrt(dMag);

      // At this point we have in B, 40,000 records each of 50 samples followed by the magnitude
      // ... and we have a single record from "a.txt" with 50 samples and its magnitude in AMagnitude
      // ... and Alineno is the absolute line number in "a.txt" of this line
      // Time to do the actual calculation: compare this record to all records in B
      for(int brec=0;brec<BLINES;brec++){
         float BMagnitude=B[brec][SAMPLESPERLINE];
         double dotproduct=0.0;
         float *a = &A[0];
         float *b = &B[brec][0];
         for(s=0;s<SAMPLESPERLINE;s++){
            dotproduct += (*a++) * (*b++);
         }
         float similarity = dotproduct/(AMagnitude*BMagnitude);
         if(similarity>0.99){
            std::cout << "Line A: " << Alineno << ", line B: " << brec << ", similarity:" << similarity << std::endl;
         }
      }
   }
   std::cerr << "Ending job: " << JobNum << ", processed " << nLines << " lines" << std::endl;

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `Makefile` is pretty simple:

```
CFLAGS= -std=c++11 -O3 -march=native

all:    generate preprocess process

generate:   generate.cpp
        clang++ ${CFLAGS} generate.cpp -o generate

preprocess: preprocess.cpp
        clang++ ${CFLAGS} preprocess.cpp -o preprocess

process:    process.cpp
        clang++ ${CFLAGS} process.cpp -o process
```

---

When you run it, it pegs the CPU for 2 minutes and looks like this:

```
time ./go
Starting job: 3
Starting job: 7
Starting job: 8
Starting job: 2
Starting job: 5
Starting job: 1
Starting job: 4
Starting job: 6
Ending job: 1, processed 5204 lines
Starting job: 9
Ending job: 2, processed 5203 lines
Ending job: 3, processed 5204 lines
Starting job: 11
Starting job: 10
Ending job: 4, processed 5204 lines
Starting job: 12
Ending job: 5, processed 5203 lines
Ending job: 6, processed 5203 lines
Starting job: 14
Starting job: 13
...
...
Starting job: 75
Ending job: 68, processed 5204 lines
Ending job: 69, processed 5203 lines
Starting job: 76
Starting job: 77
Ending job: 70, processed 5203 lines
Ending job: 71, processed 5204 lines
Ending job: 72, processed 5203 lines
Ending job: 77, processed 4535 lines
Ending job: 74, processed 5204 lines
Ending job: 73, processed 5205 lines
Ending job: 75, processed 5204 lines
Ending job: 76, processed 5203 lines

real    2m17.510s
user    16m24.533s
sys     0m4.426s
```

---

Note that I have not done any explicit SIMD or loop-unrolling or used any intrinsics to form the dot-product. I suspect if you asked a question about forming a dot-product and tagged it with `simd` or `avx`, someone would help you optimise it.

---

Note also that you could easily run this code across multiple computers with **GNU Parallel**, assuming you have `ssh` login to them, just using:

```
parallel -S host1,host2,host3 ....
```

For example, I have a 6-core Debian PC on my network, so I ran the above code parallelised across my 4-core Mac and 6-core Debian machine with:

```
parallel -S :,debian ...
```

and it then takes 1 minute 8 seconds.