# Cosine similarity between two arrays for word embeddings

Tags: python, pytorch, embedding, cosine-similarity

I am trying to find the most similar word embeddings between 2 arrays, let's say the first array `A` has dimension `[100, 50]`, where 100 is the number of words and 50 the embedding dimension, on the other hand I have many other words stored in an array `B` of dimension `[400000, 50]`, I want to find the top 10 (most similar, highest cosine similarity) words for each word from `A` in `B`. In other words, for each word in `A`, I want to find 10 words in `B` with the highest cosine similarity.

I solved it using 2 for loops, but I want to know if there is any way to do this faster since my method takes time when I increase the number of samples on `A`, any trick or advice would be helpful. I am using the cosine_similarity function from `torch`, if there is another choice that is faster, it would also be great. I have tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030945/python-cosine-similarity-between-two-large-numpy-arrays), but I would like to know if there is any better solution as this one is 5 years old. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what indexed vector databases are designed to do. Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend shared his solution, and there is a way to do it much faster, this is the code:

```
def cosine_similarity(x: Tensor, y: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    return torch.cosine_similarity(x[..., None], y.T, dim=-2)
```

This way the output is a matrix and there is no need to loop through both datasets.